# Facing HTTP error when communicate with teams bot by using teamsFx

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am facing this error ‘There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError’ in Post deployment to the Azure.
Check this image for error [Web Chat Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy4Vg.png)

And sometime running the bot in my local is not working by using the teamsFx package if I deleted the registered application in the Azure.

Below are points that I have followed to create the bot,

1. Installed the **teams toolkit** extension in the vs code.
2. Created the bot app( javascript ) using the teams toolkit which using the **@microsoft/teamsFx package**.
3. Implemented the SSO authentication using **teamsFx**.
4. Deployed the bot using the **teams toolkit**

Comment: Could you please let us know if the below response has solved your query?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bot sso sample at https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v2/bot-sso, which demonstrates how to enable SSO for bot. You may start with this sample to learn how to add SSO for your own bot.

In the meantime, there should be some logs from your bot server when error happens (besides the internal server error displayed in the screenshots). Can you paste the errors here? It will be helpful to identify the root cause for your problem.